# moment.js showing wrong date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get the date last week starting from now.

```
console.log(moment().day(-7).format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

It should show me 06.01.2017 but I am getting always 01.01.2017. I don't understand why. According to API this should work.

> // when Monday is the first day of the week
>
> moment().weekday(-7); // last Monday

http://momentjs.com/docs/

Why do I get a wrong date and how to get the right date?

Comment: use **.add** prototype instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
moment().add(Number, String);
moment().add(Duration);
moment().add(Object);
```

```js
console.log(moment().add(-7, 'days').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow. You beat me with 45 seconds with an exactly the same answer. :) I removed mine.

Comment: Hehe.. Faster.. Thanks for deleting yours

Comment: Thank you for an ultra fast answer! Do you know why I can't use my example? I got it from the api too. PS: I can't click accept right now, because need to wait 10 Minutes according to stackoverflow message.

Comment: @MeteorNewbie Your method can be used to set the day of the week, with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 6. No problem, dont forget to accept it when you can

Answer (score 6):

You should use instead:

```
moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('DD.MM.YYYY')
```

Comment: Thank you for showing another possibility.